# AJAX Request that fetches ID as well and puts that into the HTML

Tags: php, sql, ajax, search

I'm trying to make an Ajax search form - This form will simply search the database for names.

The table design is as follows:

```
id   name         age
1    some name    10
2    some name2   11
3    some name3   12
```

Each name is associated with a unique ID.

I want to create a drop down menu  of top hits when the user enters their search string.

Also, somehow in the background i would like to retrieve the associated ID with each result as well. That ID will be POST'ed to a form say

```
 myform.php
```

Now, my question is as follows:

1) How do i create the drop down menu? 
 I believe i can follow this tutorial and simply customise it to create a drop down menu.
 http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp
 This would be fairly simple.

2) The main question is, how do i keep track of the ID and selected name, so that i can POST that ID to myform.php

Thanks.

Comment: cosidered using a javascript framework like jQuery?

Comment: yes, i can consider using a framework like jQuery... infact i'm working in PHP so, i'm planning to use http://jquery4php.sourceforge.net/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="carlist">
  <option value="id">name</option>
      </select>
```

Keep id and name like this.

on posting id is posting , you can get name from id .

I hope this is what you are asking.

But i dont find drop down in that link you provide

Comment: just a small question zod, would the id in second line in HTML update as well using Ajax? I'm a newbie to the Ajax world.

Comment: Seems i can get this done using your method easily.. :) thanks a lot!